# Wait till each function (jQuery) will end

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

I've got this:

```
$.each(.., function() {
    $(this).destroy() // call ajax
});
```

I want to make sure that each function has finished and the ajax calls too.
There is anyway to do it? I've tried `$.when` function and it isn't work well.

The ajax call isn't directly, there is a function that makes for me an ajax process.
So I need to verify outside the $.ajax command.

Comment: If you want to chain those calls, perhaps using promises would be the best. Or simply calling the next one when the current one ends.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a promise:

```
var requests = [];
$.each(..., function() {
    var promise = $.ajax(...);
    requests.push(promise); 
});

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
    // all AJAX requests completed here
}).fail(function() {
    // will be called if any AJAX request failed
});
```

This being said, personally I would avoid making many AJAX calls like that in a loop. It's much more efficient to make one big AJAX call rather than many small calls.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to simply make all your ajax calls synchronous using the `async` parameter with `$.ajax`:

```
$.each(..., function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/script.php",
        async: false
    });
});
```

This way, you won't start an ajax request until the last one finishes, so you'll know that once your loop finishes, all the requests will be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Not really elegant, but it should work:

```
var numCalls = 5, ajaxes = 0;

$.each(numCalls, function(i, v) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'blah'     
    })
    .always(function(){
        ajaxes += 1;
        checkDone();
    });
});
function checkDone(){
    if(ajaxes === numCalls){
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: This should increment `ajaxes` in `.always` to account for errors (which won't cause `.done` to be triggered)

Answer (score 0):

You could make each call assign it's promise to an array, some time later check all the array elements have finished

```
var jqxhr = [];
$.each(....
    jqxhr.push($.ajax(......));
}); // end of each loop
```

check the status of each call with

```
$.each(jqxhr,function(idx,xhr) {
   if (xhr.statuscode != 200) { ... }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if you can achieve this by sending async requests. But if you are fine using sync requests, you need to add `async: false;`.

```
$.ajax({
//set properties
async: false;
//other properties
})
```

But using sync request may cause browser to wait and result in slow response time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option: use the [`ajaxStop`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/) function.

```
$.each(..., function(){
    $.ajax(...);
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    console.log("All done!");
}
```

When bound, this function checks for completed or cancelled ajax requests (including non-jQuery requests), and triggers the callback once all outstanding requests have finished. This allows you to make all the asynchronous ajax requests you want without needing to change the way the requests are actually made.

Note: If ajax calls are being made at the same time elsewhere on the page, this method will wait for those as well.